# PHPexcel save to CSV linked cells to another sheet are empty

Tags: csv, date, save, export, phpexcel

Could someone help me?
I have xlsx file, with 2 sheets.

Second sheet contain cells linked to another(first) sheet.
When I save sheet to CSV file:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
```

This function doesn't save (linked) cells value...

My code looking like this:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

//  Read your Excel workbook
try 
{
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($excelFile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly('list'); 
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly('main'); 
    /* I also tried like this: 
    $worksheetList = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($excelFile);
    $sheetname = $worksheetList[0]; 
    $sheetname2 = $worksheetList[1]; 
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($worksheetList[0]); 
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
    */
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($excelFile);
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$objWriter->save($filename);
```

I also tried to save to EXCEL files (xls and xlsx) -> the same problem, the cells (which was linked) they are empty...

My linked cells looked like this: "=list!C46"

Many hours of looking for answer, I have found not good solution:
I've removed any of these lines:         `$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly('list');` 
and add:

```
$activeSheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($activeSheetData, false);
```

just after:

`$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($excelFile);`

and also add: `$objWriter->setSheetIndex(1);` 
Now it will works, but with problems...

One column in original format have linked cells like this: **"=list!$AV$46"**
I mean with $ symbol.

More detailed:
If I have:   `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);`
and have those cells: "=list!$AV$46" then they are empty in output.

But if I remove: `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);`
then those cells: "=list!$AV$46" works good and have a value, but with format
like: 11/17/2017.

As I removed `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);`, then I can't apply
this my code:
`$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)->getStyle('AV1:AV'.$highestRow)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD);`

Then second question, how to write new date format?
I also wanted to say, that initial date format was:
17.11.2017. 
And I wanted 17-11-17 (FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD).

And again, with cells which looks like `"=list!AV46"` all works good.

**UPDATE:** Solvation: `$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(['list', 'main']);` + `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);` before any of: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->...`

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, not as an edit to question, see [tour] to learn more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your first problem

```
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly('list'); 
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly('main');
```

You're only ever loading one sheet, the last one that you tell PHPExcel to load, which is `main`. Multiple calls to `setLoadSheetsOnly()` overwrite the setting of the previous call.

If you want to load both sheets, then you need to pass an array listing all the sheetnames that you want to load

```
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(['list', 'main']);
```

This is explained in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md#reading-only-named-worksheets-from-a-file)

---

The documentation also says not to use `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);` unless you understand what it is doing; it tells PHPExcel to load only the rw data, not the formatting of data; and it is the formatting that differentiates a number from a date in Excel.

Comment: Mark Baker, thanks, actually I thought about this, after post question. 
Really, `(['list', 'main'])` - this doesn't work, but this way: array('list','main');
Now it's works thanks, but these lines stop working: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(1,20);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AV1:AV'.$highestRow)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('A')->removeColumn('B')->removeColumn('C');`

I have also tried: setActiveSheet... also doesn't work..